# Does logical replication supports bidirectional?

Tags: postgresql, replication, logical-replication

I have created two publications one on each PostgreSQL instance but on the same table. Then I subscribed to these publications from each instance. I didn't see an error in the logs of two instances but I can see replication works on one side i.e. uni-directional.

Does logical replication support bi-directional or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use logical replication to replicate the same table in both directions. This would necessitate complicated conflict resolution, which PostgreSQL doesn't have at the moment.

Comment: Since subscribing to multiple publications for the same table works provided each publication is having unique keys(like primary, constraints, etc), I thought even bidirectional will work. So now I think, I have to use BDR.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres v16 started adding a support for bidirectional replication but the feature is not complete yet.

[Release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-16-released-2715/)

> There are several access control improvements to logical replication in PostgreSQL 16, including the new predefined role pg_create_subscription, which grants users the ability to create new logical subscriptions. Finally, this release begins adding support for bidirectional logical replication, introducing functionality to replicate data between two tables from different publishers.

Comment: Postgres is working on supporting bidirectional logical replication. The feature is not yet available in postgres 16.